# Find the count of elements from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

First the schema - i have 4 tables:

```
office - officeid, officename
member - memberid, officeid, membername (multiple members per office)
transaction - transactionid, memberid, transactiontype (multiple transactions per member)
activity - activityid, officeid (multiple activities per office)
```

How can i get the list of member names, along with offices and the count of each transaction type and total count of activities for that office with a single query?

I have tried myself and i can get the office names, member names and activity count but not able to get the transaction count (per transaction type) with a single query. Wondering if this is possible at all.

Any suggestions/help is appreciated. Please let me know if i can provide any details which i missed

Edit - I added a sqlfiddle with some sample  data  at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cf7b/1

Also realized i had missed the  officeid foreign key in the member table.

Edit - Adding expected output

```
officename, membername, transaction_count_1, trasaction_count_2, activitycount
abc       , aa        , 1                  , 1,                , 3
abc       , bb        , 1                  , 0,                , 1
abc       , cc        , 0                  , 1,                , 0
```

Comment: uIn your question there is not relation between  transaction and activity .. how do you need to join these tables?... you need  somethings that join office and transaction or activity and transaction

Comment: @scaisEdge - i was joining  office and  member first and then transaction to member and activity to office for one query to  get  all results. but i could not figure  out how to  get the count  per transaction  type.

Comment: Update your question adding a proper data sample and the expected  result please

Comment: @scaisEdge - please check the edit. thanks

Comment: You have not relation between activity and transaction i .. so i think you can obtain the result you need ( or i don't understand how you can obtain the result showed)

Answer (score 0):

I think this can solve your purpose.

```
select b.membername,a.officename,count(transactiontype) 
from office a, 
member b, 
transaction c
where a.officeid = b.officeid
and b.memberid = c.memberid 
group by b.membername,a.officename
```

If you need any further data manipulation just give me an idea (perferably a screenshot or an image) of how your output shall look and i shall change the query accordingly.

Thanks.